# Hugo unable to locate config file

Tags: hugo

Hugo was running fine locally until this happened...

I'm in the same folder (check the ls), the folder *is* a hugo website, and the config.toml is named properly. What gives?

[Hugo error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THdqq.png)

Edit #1: I ran `hugo new site TEST`, then `cd TEST` and tried to run the server again... got the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for your error message is that you use the command ***hugo server -D*** incorrectly.
In your screen shot you execute the command like this: hugo **-server** -D
The dash before the server makes hugo misinterpret the command and you get the error message you mention.

The correct command is: **`hugo server -D`**

Answer (score 0):

To run your site locally with a real-time content watcher, the command is [`hugo serve`](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_server/#hugo-server) (drop the dash before `serve`).